# Getting "TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes" in serialize_blob_tags_header when uploading blob to Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

This error occurs when using attempting to upload a blob to azure with python.

```
Full error is here: 
  File "C:\Users\P3159331\OneDrive - Charter Communications\Documents - Audience Insights\5. Development\nielsen_full\devenv\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_serialize.py", line 170, in serialize_blob_tags_header
    components.append(quote(value, safe='.-'))
  File "C:\Users\P3159331\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 869, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "C:\Users\P3159331\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 894, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because I was trying to upload my tags with an int as dictionary value. Change it to a string and it fixed.

I was classifying my file and returning tags like so:
return {'date': 'string-date', 'type':'overnights','attatchment_flag':1, 'status':'staged'}

Azure didn't like my int tag value. So I changed to:
return {'date': 'string-date', 'type':'overnights','attatchment_flag':'1', 'status':'staged'}.

I couldn't find anyone else who had experienced this error so I figured I'd share.